# Java: Problems when calling methods and instantiating objects from another class

Tags: java, class, object, methods, instantiation

I am an AP Computer Programming student and I am having quite a bit of trouble understanding how to call methods to a driver program defined in one class , as well as create objects in the driver class  from the constructor of the non-driver class. My book has the following class, with the program's intent being to simulate the flipping of a coin:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Coin{

        private int HEADS = 0;
        private int TAILS = 1;

        private int face;

        Coin mycoin = new Coin();

        public Coin(){

        flip();
        }

        public void flip(){

            face = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
        }

        public boolean isHeads(){

            return (face == HEADS);
        }

        public String toString(){

            String faceName;

            if (face == HEADS)
                faceName = "Heads";
            else
                faceName = "Tails";

            return faceName;
        }
}
```

Here is an example driver program from the book as well:

```
public class FlipRace
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    final int NUM_FLIPS = 1000;
    int heads = 0, tails = 0;

    Coin myCoin = new Coin();

    for (int count = 1; count <= NUM_FLIPS; count++)
    {
      myCoin.flip();

      if (myCoin.isHeads())
        heads++;
      else
        tails++;
    }

    System.out.println("The number of flips: " + NUM_FLIPS);
    System.out.println("The number of heads: " + heads);
    System.out.println("The number of tails: " + tails);   
  }
}
```

The problem I have is that when I try to recreate the driver program or make any driver program, the driver program seems to be unable to call upon the customized classes of the constructor. I get errors like:

```
cannot find symbol
  symbol:  Class Coin
  location:  Class (name of driver program)
```

I honestly have no idea what the problem is. It had been said to me that a separate .java file was needed in order to access the constructor, but I couldn't find a way to do that. Was that person wrong? Am I supposed to put the main method and the constructor all on one program? If not that, how do I call upon methods from another class?

I've been struggling with this for almost a week, so any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**: The spelling errors in the for loop were my own. They are not present in the actual program. I have now fixed them.

Comment: Even if you manage to compile your code `Coin mycoin = new Coin();` in the `Coin` class will get you into trouble (=`StackOverflowError`). Also if that book *was* a good one, the `HEADS` and `TAILS` fields would be `static` and `final` (since both should be constants).

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the driver and the `Coin` class are in the same package (or that you import the package `Coin` is in), it appears that you have them both in the default package.
2. Compile `Coin.java` before (or at the same time) as the driver `javac *.java`
3. Make sure you specify a classpath that includes the current folder when you execute the driver like

   java -cp . FlipRace

Finally,

```
for (inc count = 1; counr <= NUM_FLIPS; count++)
```

should be

```
for (int count = 1; count <= NUM_FLIPS; count++)
```

I haven't exhaustively searched your code for more typos.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this by reoving this code from Coin Class

```
Coin mycoin = new Coin();

    public Coin(){

    flip();
    }
```

and made changes in the line of for loop in FlipRace

```
    for (int count = 1; count <= NUM_FLIPS; count++)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best advice that can be given here is to research the basics of Java packages. This is a good place to start: [Java packages tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html)

It covers such topics as:

- Creating and Using Packages
- Using Package Members
- Managing Source and Class Files

Having read that, you should be able to understand the problems you are facing.